# Generate random matrix with specific values

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I am new to MATLAB and I want to create a random n*n matrix containing just -1 OR 1 as values.
any help ?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask an than add details and code to your question.

Comment: "Random" doesn't mean anything unless you specify the (joint) distribution of the entries

Answer (score 2):

I would use `randi`

```
% Generate random array of 0s and 1s, *2 and -1 to give random values -1 or +1
m = randi([0,1], n)*2-1
```

See also: [introductory docs on random integers](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-integers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `randi` to generate the indexes of the numbers I am interested in. E.g. in your case you are interested in the numbers

```
a= [-1,1];
```

Thus we use

```
b = randi(length(a),2,2); %Generate matrix of size 2x2
```

to generate a random set of indexes. Finally we simply convert the indexes to the numbers of interest.

```
c = a(b); %Now a 2x2 matrix of -1, 1 numbers
```

Answer (score -1):

```
A=rand(n);
thres=rand(1); % or whatever percentage
A=A>thres; % 1 and 0
A(A==0)=-1; % makes 0 -1
```